# How to compose 2 videos by using FFmpeg hstack filter?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to compose 2 videos into 1 video by putting side by side.
I also hope to set start/stop time for each video.
Final video should be H264/AAC codec and mp4 format.
I attached sample videos.
 https://www.dropbox.com/s/e5eouyrrqsy44ts/1.webm?dl=0
 https://www.dropbox.com/s/u0zqie0icxamt3q/2.webm?dl=0

I used the following ffmpeg command.

**ffmpeg -i 1.webm -i 2.webm -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]hstack" output.mp4**

When I run this command on Terminal of Mac OS X 10.11, It gave me the following error.

**Input 1 height 480 does not match input 0 height.**

The video are from smartphone, so its orientation is not correct.
Please help me to make composed video with FFmpeg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this set of videos, you need

```
ffmpeg -i 1.webm -i 2.webm -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=480:640,setsar=1[l];[1:v]scale=480:640,setsar=1[r];[l][r]hstack;[0][1]amix" -vsync 0 output.mp4
```

The writing application hasn't written the stream attributes correctly. The videos should be tagged as 480x640. It's not about a missing rotation tag, as the frame context changes.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer, Mulvya.

Comment: I also want to set video start, stop time in final video timeframe. For example, If I want to start video1 start at 200ms and stop at 50000ms in final video timeline, What can I do now? In this case, video1 duration  is about 60000ms, so it needs to play only 50000-200=49800ms of video1 part. We can use any ffmpeg filter such as pad.

Comment: Insert `-ss 0.2 -t 49.8` before `-i 1.webm`. This will change the sync between video 1 and 2.

Comment: if I want to insert 0s~50s part of video1 to 1s~51s in final result video and 4s~30s part of video2 to 2s~28s in final result video, what can I do? I want to set start/stop offset for each video in final result video. Thanks.

Comment: Not clear. You want to show 1-51s of 1 in left and 4-30s of 2 in right?