# Unsplitting two video files with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I cannot find a better word for this, because I searched for "combine", "join", "merge", "concat" and each time I get the information on how to get two videos into one so that the resulting file will play first video and then continues to the second one. I, on the other hand, need them to play simultaneously in the resulting video, so that first file goes to the left, and the second one to the right. It is a video chat recording of two person web cameras that need to get into one file to play at once. How to do that with ffmpeg?

Comment: You're looking for a [mosaic](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20mosaic%20out%20of%20several%20input%20videos)

Comment: For your specific case, [hstack](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hstack) is what you want. See this answer for an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39218961/how-to-compose-2-videos-by-using-ffmpeg-hstack-filter/39220071?s=1|2.2202#39220071).

Comment: @Mulvya Good find, I didn't know about that one